# Monitor 200+ SFTP Subfolders through Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have 200 + SFTP Sub folders and it will be dynamically adding 10 folders every month. We created List rows in a table through Onedrive and started monitoring the SFTP location, but somehow this approach is missing some files at certain point.. Is there better way or different approach to tackle this problem.. Has anyone came across in the past?

Comment: Please share more information

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that, is the Onedrive file with the table perhaps in a locked state and can't be accessed by logic apps? That is the most similar issue I have had in the past.

Is this one Logic App or multiple Logic Apps? If it is one logic app you could try to make this into an app that only checks the list of dynamically added folders which would kick of an Azure automation job that would deploy new logic apps for each line(folder) which would monitor the folders, though with this approach you would end up with 200+ logic apps, not that it is anything wrong with that, besides the limit per resource group is 800.